# Github Pages 404 not found issue

Tags: github-pages

I am having issues with my site. I have a repository for git hub pages Godoflaugh.github.io and I am trying to view a project I am working on https://godoflaugh.github.io/Module2/ . The issue is that I keep receiving the 404 file not found issue. My index.html file is in the root directory and I've re-pushed files to see if the commit would take effect and show anything. Please help!

Comment: did you follow the steps to create a site from your github repo? https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site

Comment: Yes, I ended up fixing it. Not sure what the issue was but I recreated the repository and synced everything back up again and it worked. I did change the name of Index.html to index.html. Not sure if github is picky about capitilization.

Comment: yes, GitHub (and their underlying systems) would be picky about capitalizations - you didn't mention `Index.html` in your question (but `index.html`) so that didn't trigger a flag for me

Comment: Gotcha, that is good to know for the future! Thank you!